# Group and sort by associated table attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

There are two tables, Group sections and Groups.

I want to group and sort groups by group sections.

**Group Sections:**

```
Id | Name       | Priority
1  | Football   | 2
2  | Basketball | 1
3  | Tennis     | 3
```

**Groups:**

```
Id | section_id | Name 
1  | 1          | Barcelona
2  | NULL       | Noname
3  | 1          | Real Madrid
4  | 2          | Cedevita 
5  | 3          | Ljubljana
```

What i got for now in sql:

```
  SELECT  group_sections.id, group_sections.priority AS priority, group_sections.name, groups.*
  FROM groups 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN group_sections ON group_sections.group_id = groups.id
  GROUP BY group_sections.id, groups.id
  ORDER BY group_sections.priority ASC
```

What I want to get:

`Football => [<Group id: 1>, <Group id: 3], Basketball => [<Group id: 2>], Tennis => [<Group id: 3]`

How can I get this in rails **active record?**

```
@groups.joins(:group_sections).group('group_sections.id', 'groups.id').order('group_sections.priority ASC')
```

This query is not working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `string_agg`

```
select string_agg(name || ' => [' || groupnames ,', ')  groupnames
from(
SELECT b.name,  string_agg(a.name,', ') || ']' groupnames
FROM groups1 a
JOIN group_sections b ON b.id = a.sectionid
group by a.sectionid, b.name, b.priority
order by b.priority) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql has useful function for it named **string_agg**. Here example for your situation:

```
with 
    gs as (
        select 1 as id, 'Football' as name, 2 as Priority union all
        select 2 as id, 'Basketball' as name, 1 as Priority union all
        select 3 as id, 'Tennis' as name, 3 as Priority
        ),
    g as (
        select 1 as id, 1 as section_id, 'Barcelona' as Name union all
        select 2 as id, null as section_id, 'Noname' as Name union all
        select 3 as id, 1 as section_id, 'Real Madrid' as Name union all
        select 4 as id, 2 as section_id, 'Cedevita ' as Name
        )
select 
     gs.id, gs.name, gs.Priority,
     string_agg(g.id::text,',') as id_of_groups
from g 
left join gs 
    on g.section_id = gs.id
group by gs.id, gs.name, gs.Priority
order by gs.Priority
```